# Writing time to a file in C using time.h

Tags: c

So basically I've got this project in C - I have to design a customer/order system, in which the customer can make multiple orders but each order is limited to a single product type. I created a struct 'orders' which contains the customer ID, product name, price, and the order time. Here is the code to calculate time:

```
        // computing order time
        time_t timeorder;
        char * displayT;
        timeorder = time(NULL);
        // convert time to string so that it can be displayed
        displayT= ctime(&timeorder);
        printf("Your order time is: %s\n", displayT); //check if time displays correctly
        newOrders11[count13].timeorder = displayT;
```

Immediately after, the struct 'orders' is written to file. After the user makes an order, he/she should be available to view his/her LATEST order after entering his/her ID number. However, when the order is read from the file, the first order the user made (rather than the latest) is displayed. Here is the code for reading from file:

```
 while (count13<=MAXORDERSTOBEMADE && (fread(&newOrders11[count13], sizeof(struct orders), 1, filePointer))==1)
{
    if(ID == newOrders11[count13].ID) {
        printf("These are the details for order %i\n", count13);

        if(count13>=0)
        printf("Customer ID: %d\n", newOrders11[count13].ID);
        printf("Product Name: %s\n", newOrders11[count13].productname);
        printf("Price: %f\n", newOrders11[count13].total);
    } else {
        continue;
    }
    count13++;
}
```

Does any one know how I should go about this? Sorry, I am still a C beginner. This is my first program in C.

Comment: It sounds like new records are added at the end of the file.  If so, you either need to read backwards from the end of the file (which is more practical if the entries are a fixed size than if they vary in length), or you read through the file, keeping a copy of the last record that matches the given ID, and only printing the information when you've reached the end of the file.

Comment: The number-suffixed variable names like `newOrders11` and `count13` are unusual.  Not formally wrong, but unusual.

Comment: what is `count13` and `newOrders11` vs `newOrders`? Typos?

Comment: Where do you seek to the correct record?  You might find `ftell` and `fseek` useful.

Comment: I used these just for the moment, so that I will be able to distinguish for my old(somewhat bugged) code, and any new code I will write to try and fix the problem. They won't be number-suffixed in the final code. Thanks for your replies! :-)

Comment: @KarthikT - yes you are right. The if statement should contain newOrders11. Sorry for any misunderstanding... my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `while` loop, you're only testing against the customer ID, so the first record for that customer will match.

Given that records in the file are ordered by timestamp, it might be better to start reading from the end of the file, rather than the beginning:

```
fseek(filePointer, -sizeof (struct orders), SEEK_END);
while (count13 <= MAXORDERSTOBEMADE && (fread(...) == 1))
{
  if (ID == ...)
  {
     ...
  }    
  else
  {
    fseek(filePointer, -2 * sizeof(struct orders), SEEK_CUR);
  }
}
```

Caveats:  `SEEK_END` may not be supported for binary streams, and arbitrary offsets may not be meaningful for text streams:

> #### 7.21.9.2 The fseek function
>
> 2 The `fseek` function sets the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by `stream`.
>    If a read or write error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and `fseek` fails.
> 3 For a binary stream, the new position, measured in characters from the beginning of the
>  file, is obtained by adding offset to the position specified by `whence`. The specified
>       position is the beginning of the file if whence is `SEEK_SET`, the current value of the file
>          position indicator if `SEEK_CUR`, or end-of-file if `SEEK_END`. A binary stream need not
>           meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a `whence` value of `SEEK_END`.
> 4 For a text stream, either `offset` shall be zero, or `offset` shall be a value returned by
>  an earlier successful call to the `ftell` function on a stream associated with the same file
>   and `whence` shall be `SEEK_SET`.

Comment: I would recommend this approach only if performance is of the essence. With the caveats it's a bit complicated for a beginner doing her first homework assignment.

Comment: Hey I just tried this and it works! Wow great thanks so much for your help :)))

Answer (score 0):

You need to scan through the whole file until you are sure you will not see any more orders. In other words, when you see EOF (end-of-file), you should print the last match you found.

- So, read through the entire file, one record at a time.
- If you find a match, store it temporarily in variables for later printing (overwriting any previous match - you only need to remember the last one found).

(optionally, you may want to compare the timestamps and ignore matches with older timestamps. If your file is written in timestamp order this step can be omitted)

- After reading through the whole file, print the values of the variables where you stored the latest record.